# changing cities according to states with jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .post

I want to know difference between $.ajax and $.post in jquery. I search it but not getting clearification. Actually I am having drop down of states and cities and I am changing cities when states changes with jquery $.post.
Here is my code of jquery

```
$.post('includes/change_cities.php', { 'state_id': state_id },
        function( data ) {
        var content = $( data );
        $( "#cities" ).empty().append( content );
        }
        );
```

My Problem is when states changes for the first time it takes too much time to change cities about 4 to 5 seconds but after first time it becomes normal means changes cities without taking any time. So Is there any problem in my code or should I use any other method for this.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance Depends on your code and sql implementation.
$.post is subset of $.ajax in tersm of functionality.

> $.ajax({ 
>     **type: 'POST'**, 
>     url: 'ajax/test.html', 
>     data: data, 
>     success: function(data){ 
>   $('.result').html(data) 
>   },
>   });

is Equivalent to

> $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) { 
>     $('.result').html(data);
>   });

Comment: Ok I got the difference bwteen $.ajax and $.post. It's fine ow thanx for this but that problem is not solving/

Comment: If you could, do share your "change_cities.php" and sql table implementation.

Comment: Try  EXPLAIN on the SQL you are running to fetch the Cities. That may hold the answer.

Comment: Problem is solved now. This was happening because of browser. I cleaned cookies and cache then now it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try their docs. They are quite good. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

> $.post is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Can't say why it is slow. Have you tried inspecting your response times from your server?

Comment: I had used it but no benefit in the first time it is getting hanged.

Comment: Inspecting your server response times has nothing to do with benefits. It has everything to do with performance. What is your server doing? Try fiddler to inspect.

Comment: @mrtshermanProblem is solved now. This was happening because of browser. I cleaned cookies and cache then now it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$.post()` and `$.get()` are both shorthand functions provided by jQuery that are really just calling `$.ajax()`.

Additionally, I can assure you that AJAX calls do not take 4 to 5 seconds on the first call as a warmup penalty.